# Issue with Google oAuth2 callback using Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I would like use Firebase Functions to use the Google Developer API. Authentification is required to use this API.

I follow the doc: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client

I have some troubles to get the authorization code in the callback url.

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
google.options({ auth: oauth2Client });

var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  'XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'XXXX',
  'https://us-central1-XXXX.cloudfunctions.net/oauth2callback'
);

function generateAuthenticationUrl() {

  return oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'
  });
}

exports.oauth2Callback = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.code);
  const code = req.query.code;
  //do something
  return null;
});


exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var url = generateAuthenticationUrl();
  console.log(url);

  //-> url print in the console is : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fandroidpublisher&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXX-XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-XXX.cloudfunctions.net%2Foauth2callback

  res.redirect(url);
});
```

Redirect url is set in the Google Console Developer:

[image: OAuth 2.0 client IDs]

When I call the url `https://us-central1-XXX.cloudfunctions.net/hello`, I got "Error: could not handle the request" and "finished with status: 'timeout'" in the Firebase logs.

What's wrong?

Comment: Hi, have you tried retrieving the access token, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Also, are you following this step-by-step [guide](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client) thoroughly?

Comment: I posted my solution using JWT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Full code using JWT to authenticate, then get the list of app's reviews:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var {google} = require('googleapis');
const serviceAccount = require('./client_secret.json');
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');


const getAuthorizedClient = () => new JWT({
    email: serviceAccount.client_email,
    key: serviceAccount.private_key,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
});

const getAndroidpublisher = () => google.androidpublisher({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: getAuthorizedClient()
});



const requestProductValidation = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    getAndroidpublisher().reviews.list({
            packageName: "com.my.packagename"
        }, (err, response) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`);
            resolve({status: "Error"});
        } else {

           return resolve(response);

        }
    });
});


exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {   
      return requestProductValidation();
});
```